# Let $\Phi$ be the distribution function of $Z \sim N(0,1)$.Find $E[Z \Phi(Z)]$ and $E[Z^2 \Phi(Z)]$.

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution, expected-value

Let $\Phi$ be the distribution function of $Z \sim N(0,1)$.Find $E[Z \Phi(Z)]$ and $E[Z^2 \Phi(Z)]$.
In the first case, I am struggling with the integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} z^2 \Phi(z) \phi(z) dz$ How to evaluate this?

Comment: Have a look at the [list of integrals of Gaussian functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_integrals_of_Gaussian_functions).

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2600855/321264, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2855794/321264

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On base of $\Phi(z)+\Phi(-z)=1$ we find:$$Z^2=Z^2\Phi(Z)+(-Z)^2\Phi(-Z)\tag1$$

$Z$ and $-Z$ have the same distribution, so also $Z^2\Phi(Z)$ and $(-Z)^2\Phi(-Z)$ have the same distribution.

Then taking expectation on both sides of $(1)$ we find:$$1=\mathsf EZ^2=2\mathsf EZ^2\Phi(Z)$$

So: $$\mathsf EZ^2\Phi(Z)=\frac12$$

Answer (score 2):

We have $$(-z)^2 \Phi(-z) \phi(-z) = z^2 (1-\Phi(z)) \phi(z)$$ and so

$$\begin{align*}\int_{-\infty}^{0} z^2 \Phi(z) \phi(z) dz &= \int_{0}^{\infty} (-z)^2 \Phi(-z) \phi(-z) dz\\ &= \int_{0}^{\infty} z^2  \phi(z) dz - \int_{0}^{\infty} z^2 \Phi(z) \phi(z) dz\end{align*}$$

And we get:

$$\begin{align*}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} z^2 \Phi(z) \phi(z) dz &= \int_{-\infty}^{0} z^2 \Phi(z) \phi(z) dz + \int_{0}^{\infty} z^2 \Phi(z) \phi(z) dz \\ &= \left(\int_{0}^{\infty} z^2  \phi(z) dz - \int_{0}^{\infty} z^2 \Phi(z) \phi(z) dz\right) + \int_{0}^{\infty} z^2 \Phi(z) \phi(z) dz\\ &= \int_{0}^{\infty} z^2  \phi(z) dz \\&= \frac{1}{2}E[Z^2] = \frac{1}{2}\end{align*}$$

But actually you can have this much easier just use the expectation:
$$\begin{align*}E[Z^2 \Phi(Z)] &= E[Z^2 \Phi(Z) 1_{Z\le 0}] + E[Z^2 \Phi(Z) 1_{Z\ge 0}] \\ &= E[Z^2 \Phi(-Z) 1_{Z\ge 0}] + E[Z^2 \Phi(Z) 1_{Z\ge 0}] \\ &= E[Z^2 1_{Z \ge 0}] = \frac{1}{2}\end{align*}$$ The same you can do with $E[Z \Phi(Z)]$