# Product of cdf and pdf of normal distribution.

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

> A continuos random variable $X$ has the density
>   $$
> f(x) = 2\phi(x)\Phi(x), ~x\in\mathbb{R}
> $$
>   then
>
> (*A*) $E(X) > 0$
>
> (*B*) $E(X) < 0$
>
> (*C*) $P(X\leq 0) > 0.5$
>
> (*D*) $P(X\ge0) < 0.25$
>
> \begin{eqnarray}
> \Phi(x) &=& \text{Cumulative distribution function of } N(0,1)\\
> \phi(x) &=& \text{Density function of } N(0, 1)
> \end{eqnarray}

I don't have a slightest clue where to start with. Can someone give me a little push. I saw some answers on same question like this but I didn't understand how should I integrate it when calculating expectation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It holds $$\left(\Phi^2(x)\right)' = 2\Phi(x)\varphi(x)$$

So we have $$P(X \le x) = \Phi^2(x)$$

And we can conclude $$P(X \le 0) = 0.25$$
$$P(X \ge 0) = 1 - P(X < 0) = 0.75$$

For the expectation we get:

$$\begin{align*} E[X] &= \int_0^\infty (1-\Phi^2(x)) dx - \int_{-\infty}^0 \Phi^2(x) dx \\ &= \int_0^\infty (1-\Phi^2(x)) dx - \int_{0}^\infty \Phi^2(-x) dx \\ &= \int_0^\infty (1-\Phi^2(x)) dx - \int_{0}^\infty (1-\Phi(x))^2 dx \\ &= 2 \int_0^\infty \Phi(x)(1-\Phi(x)) dx  > 0\end{align*}$$

Comment: B is the correct answer?

Comment: $$E[X] =  \int_{-\infty}^\infty x \cdot \Phi'(x)^{2}\ dx =$$ Now by parts $$ 0 -  \int_{-\infty}^\infty 1 \cdot \Phi(x)^{2}\ dx < 0 $$ ? right?

Comment: No, with integration by parts you won't get $$0 -  \int_{-\infty}^\infty 1 \cdot \Phi(x)^{2}\ dx < 0$$ but $$\infty -  \int_{-\infty}^\infty 1 \cdot \Phi(x)^{2}\ dx < 0 = \infty - \infty$$ what is undefined.
I edited my answer a bit to be correct… the first inequality was just wrong.

Comment: Which formula you used to compute expectation in your answer?

Comment: Is F the distribution function of X it holds $$E[X] = \int_0^\infty (1-F(x)) dx - \int_{-\infty}^0 F(x) dx$$

Comment: In book i saw the first portion all the time.So the second portion was always there or it just me having strange thoughts?

Comment: $$E[X] = \int_0^\infty (1-F(x)) dx$$ just hold for non-negative random variables. In general for random variable with densities $f$ it holds $$E[X] = \int_0^\infty (1-F(x)) dx - \int_0^\infty F(-x) dx = \int_0^\infty (1-F(x)) dx - \int_{-\infty}^0 F(x) dx$$ what easily can be seen by using Fubinis Theorem and $$F(x) = \int_{-\infty}^x f(x) dx$$

Comment: Thanks i just started learning all these things . My skills will grow with time. Any tips to beginner ?

Comment: @Gono You wrote $P(X \le 0) = P(X \ge 0) = 0.25$. It is impossible. Sum of this probabilities should be greater or equal to $1$.

Comment: Ofc… fixed it. Thx.

Comment: @Gono I was checking this again. Can you tell me how $P(X\leq0)=.25$

Comment: We had $$P(X \le x) = \Phi^2(x)$$ just plug in $x=0$ to get: $$P(X \le 0) = \Phi^2(0) = \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2 = \frac{1}{4}$$

Comment: Oh yes. Thank you

Comment: I am curious: What is the significance of taking the product of the PDF and CDF?

Comment: @nashynash The significance here is that you can easily conclude the original CDF as a squared one when you know the densitiy is the doubled product of CDF and PDF because it holds for any CDF $F$ with density $f$ that $(F^2)' = 2Ff$.

Answer (score 9):

This question requires no calculations.
You should not integrate anything to answer it.

**The Key**
If
$\phi(x)$ is the density function of a distribution $D$,
and
$\Phi(x)$ is the cumulative distribution function of $D$,
then
the density $f(x) = 2\phi(x)\Phi(x)$
corresponds to the distribution of a random variable $X$ defined 
as the greater of two random variables (say $D_1,D_2$) picked according to $D$.

**Why you would see this**
To see this from the formula for $f$, see that $\phi(x)$ corresponds to the chance that $D_1$ has a certain value, and $\Phi(x)$ is the chance that another sample $D_2$ has a lesser value.  Finally, the factor of 2 is for the alternative case that actually $D_2$ had this value and was greater, so together, $f(x)$ is the chance that $x$ is the greater of two randomly picked values.

Once you see this, answering the question is easy and requires no calculations.

A: Yes, you expect the higher of two samples to be greater on average than what you expect for just the first sample, since the second sample can only make the maximum go up.  (Remember $0$ is the expected value of a single sample of $N(0,1)$.)

B: No, you don't expect it to be lower.

C: Will the greater of two samples of $N(0,1)$ be negative more than half the time?  Of course not!  (It will be negative 1/4 of the time -- when both samples are negative.)

D: Will the greater sample be positive less than 1/4 of the time?  Of course not!  (It will be positive 3/4 of the time -- when either sample is positive.)

Comment: Related [link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/139072/distribution-of-the-maximum-of-two-correlated-normal-variables) and [link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/206135/expectation-of-the-maximum-of-two-correlated-normal-variables)

Answer (score 7):

An intuitive way to see that A) holds is the following:

Forget about the $2$ in front, it won't change the sign of the integral. Now, if there was only $\phi(x)$, you would get zero, because we know what

$$\int _\mathbb R x\phi(x) dx = 0$$

Now you multiply the integrand by $\Phi(x)$. Being a cumulative distribution function, it starts from $0$ and goes to $1$. In $0$, it is $0.5$. This means that $\Phi(x)$ is bigger for $x$ positive than for $x$ negative; that is, $x > 0, y < 0 \implies \Phi(x) > \Phi(y)$. Therefore, the positive parts will have bigger weight than the negative parts. And since before they balanced out to give $0$, now the positive part wins and we have 
$$\int _\mathbb R x\phi(x)\Phi(x) dx > 0$$

More formally,

$$\int _\mathbb R x\phi(x)\Phi(x) dx = \int _{-\infty}^0 x\phi(x)\Phi(x) dx + \int _0^{+\infty} x\phi(x)\Phi(x) dx > 0.5\left(\int _\mathbb R x\phi(x) dx\right) = 0$$

Comment: That was very helpful thanks i am new to these things of statistics and in simple language you wrote thanks again.

Comment: @Daman You're welcome :-)

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

If $x>0$ then $f(-x)<f(x)$

Answer (score 2):

The required expectation is nothing but $2\mathbb E(X\Phi(X))$ where $X\sim\mathcal N(0,1)$.

Integrating by parts ( taking $\Phi(x)$ as 1st function and $x\phi(x)$ as 2nd function) and using the fact that $\phi'(x)=-x\phi(x)$, it can be shown that

$$\mathbb E(X\Phi(X))=\int_{\mathbb R}x\Phi(x)\phi(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$$

$$\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad=\int_{\mathbb R}\frac{1}{2\pi}e^{-x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi}}$$

**Edit.**

Integrating by parts, $\displaystyle\int_{\mathbb{R}}\Phi(x)x\phi(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=\lim_{A\to\infty}\left(-\Phi(x)\phi(x)\big|_{-A}^A\right)+\int_{\mathbb{R}}\phi(x)\phi(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$

The limit is $0$ because $\phi(x)\to0$ whenever $x\uparrow\infty$ or $x\downarrow-\infty$

Comment: $\Phi'(x)\not=-x\phi(x)$

Comment: @NCh Definitely not. I meant $\phi$ in the l.h.s.

Comment: Can you show how your second integral is deduced from the first one?

Comment: @NCh I added a couple of lines.

Comment: Thank you, very elegant. I did not know that the expectation of the maximum of two independent normal can be found analytically.

Comment: @StubbornAtom are you from India ? I am using this book for my exam.

Comment: $\phi'(x)=-x\phi(x)$ How  ? Can someone tell me?

Comment: @Daman Nothing to tell. Differentiate $\phi(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-x^2/2}$ wrt $x$ to see for yourself.

Comment: @StubbornAtom got it.

Comment: In fact, the integral has also been evaluated in this post:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1242305/clever-way-of-finding-int-0-infty-x-phix-phixdx.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/327245/321264.