# Expectation of a Normal r.v. multiplied by a CDF

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, expected-value

Suppose a random variable $x$ is distributed $\mathcal{N}(\bar{x},\sigma^2)$. I am wondering if there is a way to derive the expectation of this variable multiplied by a Normal CDF: $$\mathbb{E}[x*\Phi(x)]$$ where $\Phi$ is the CDF of a standard Normal random variable. And is $x*\Phi(x)$ a truncated normal r.v.?

Comment: Please use standard notation to make the question readable

Comment: For standard normal $x$, this is done here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2855794/321264

Comment: I don't understand why you say that $x \Phi(x)$ is a truncated normal random variable.  If there isn't a trunctated normal distribution, then the expectation is $\frac{1}{2} \left(\mu +\frac{\sigma }{\sqrt{\pi }}\right)$.

Comment: Let $X$  be a random variable with density function $p(x)$ and $f(x)$ some function.  Then $E(Xf(X))=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xf(x)p(x)dx$.

Comment: This looks like an integration by parts problem.